# Change CSS Class of a Table After Dropdown Select

Tags: jquery, css, forms, dropdown

I have a country dropdown selection that has values like

```
<option value="blue">Singapore</option>
<option value="Sint Maarten">Sint Maarten</option>
<option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
<option value="blue">Slovenia</option>
```

and I have a table with the opening tag

```
<table class="tkt-slctr-tbl">
```

When somebody selects a dropdown select with the value "blue" I want a table class appended so the table opening tag becomes

```
<table class="blue tkt-slctr-tbl">
```

any idea ? I have tried a similar jquery solution I found here but didn't seem to apply/work for what Im going for

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/change, http://api.jquery.com/val, http://api.jquery.com/addClass

Answer (score 0):

you can try as below.

Your code

```
 <select id="name">
    <option value="blue">Singapore</option>
    <option value="Sint Maarten">Sint Maarten</option>
    <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
    <option value="blue">Slovenia</option>
 </select>
```

give a id in Table

```
<table id="table" class="tkt-slctr-tbl">
```

add below Jquery code

```
$( "#name" ).change(function() {
   var class= $('#name').val();

   $("#table").removeClass();
   $( "#table" ).addClass( "tkt-slctr-tbl "+class );
});
```